# Cant get image bundle data in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My Intent activity starting code to open camera is as follow

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
      getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  }
```

Note:- This functionality is in a class extending `dialogfragment` class

My `OnActivityResult` method,which is in the Activity class,is as follows

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("sdf",""+data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mimageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimageView4);
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        //mimageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

The error  showing in the log is as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/22615 flg=0x1 }} to activity {www.vyrazu.com.purpleknights/www.vyrazu.com.purpleknights.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

What is the problem in this code.Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Your `startActivityForResult()` is using `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Your `onActivityResult()` is using `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_FROM_GALLERY`. These are not the same. Hence, your `onActivityResult()` code is not going to process this specific result from `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();`. There are no Extras so `extras` will be null. Dont use 'extras' when it is null. Now you have a `NullPointerException` Clearly visible in the log. You could have formatted that string as now you force us to scroll endlessly.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your observation.But that is for the pick image from gallery portion.Basically both are same .I am editing the question .sorry

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your code appears to be fine. However, it relies on `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and [many camera apps have bugs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). You might wish to try your app with a different camera app and see what the results are.